# Is it possible to create an artificial Black Hole?

Tags: black-hole, universe

I am quite curious about black holes. Once I just thought whether it is possible to create an artificial Black Hole, i.e. an human made black hole. Also explain there formation if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been a lot of speculation, whether it's possible with particle accelerators to create [micro black holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole). [This is only feasible, if space is higher dimensional on very short distances](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0106295). This kind of black holes would be very short-lived due to decay by [Hawking radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation). This kind of black holes could be detected by their decay products.

[There seems to be no evidence, that black holes have formed in a particle accelerator](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20130716-will-we-ever-create-a-black-hole).

In standard 3d space the smallest black hole needs the energy-equivalent of more than $10^{19}\mbox{GeV}$ of the [Planck mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_mass) of about $20\mu\mbox{g}$ to form. That's far beyond the energy a [particle collider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider) can focus onto a single particle collision.

Even the [most energetic cosmic rays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high-energy_cosmic_ray) are several orders of magnitude below the needed energy.

LHC provided up to 8 TeV (8,000 GeV) for proton-proton collisions, scheduled are 13 TeV for the upgrade. That's 15 orders of magnitude below a smallest 3d black hole, but might allow short-lived black holes for higher-dimensional space. [This way LHC can constrain the structure of space on short distances](http://pprc.qmul.ac.uk/~rizvi/Talks/QuantumBlackHoles.pdf).

Comment: so @Gerald at which extent of energy level had humans reached?

Comment: hmm....10^19 Gev is really a great amount of energy. I wonder if we could.

Comment: @Suyog Never ever. Not in three dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

It is thought likely that black holes would produce Hawking radiation and evaporate.  We can't yet describe the end products of an evaporating black hole, and space is too warm to detect Hawking radiation anywhere.  There are some recent new ideas regarding complementarity that are difficult to reach a decision on as well.

Hawking seems to be pulling away from the black hole concept recently.  I don't know what to make of that.

Regarding particle colliders: every few years some team gets into the general news cycle with an announcement about detections that resemble particular models of black hole behavior.  Miscommunication tends to produce journalism about real black holes being created.  Now there may be developing interest in the possibility of the galactic core lighting up.  Maybe that would lead to better journalism.